Does cutting out the surfaces with no surface charge affect the charge distribution on the remaining parts of a conducting surface of arbitrary shape?
Assume that we have an arbitrary conducting surface being charged positively/negatively. Also, assume that we have extracted charge distribution by solving the Poisson's equation with proper boundary conditions. If, according to the Poisson solution, there are some areas on the conducting surface with zero or extremely low charge density, what happens if we cut off and remove these uncharged surfaces (the remaining surface becomes no longer closed)? I am eager to know whether or not it upsets the charge density for the remaining parts of the conducting surface. Indeed, I want to know if the previous charge distribution changes as we remove those uncharged surfaces, and we may need to resolve the Poisson equation for the remaining surface to obtain the new charge distribution.

every time you "cut out" something, it's better to tell what you put in that cut: "vacuum"?

@basics Yes, vacuum.

Removing the uncharged parts of a charge distribution would not change the field configuration elsewhere. To show this, start with the Poisson equation (assuming the permittivity $\epsilon_0$ is the same everywhere and working in units where $\epsilon_0 = 1$):
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 V(\vec{r}) = -\rho(\vec{r}).
\end{equation}
Since this is a linear equation, you can decompose the total potential into the potential caused by different parts of the charge distribution. We can divide our system into $i$ disjoint parts,
\begin{align}
V(\vec{r}) &= \Sigma_i V_i(\vec{r}) \\
\rho(\vec{r}) &= \Sigma_i \rho_i(\vec{r})
\end{align}
such that each component satisfies the Poisson equation
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 V_i(\vec{r}) = -\rho_i(\vec{r}).
\end{equation}
This is simply the principle of superposition. It is now easy to see that the parts that are uncharged (i.e. $\rho_i = 0$) will contribute nothing to the overall potential. On removing them and running the decomposition backwards to reconstruct the Poisson equation for the full distribution, you can see that the overall potential $V(\vec{r})$ remains unchanged.
Note: if your material carrying the charge has permittivity $\epsilon \neq \epsilon_0$, then the field in the volume once occupied by the removed part will reduce by a factor of $\epsilon/\epsilon_0$. However, the field outside this volume will be unchanged as long as the removed part is uncharged.

Thanks for the answer, however, I wonder if removing the uncharged parts does not affect Poisson's equation being applied to the remaining parts since the remaining surface is no longer closed meaning that the electric field is now allowed to appear in the vacuum spaces that were previously filled with uncharged conducting parts.

The answer above applies to all materials - whether they are perfect conductors or not. In the specific case of conductors, before removal of the uncharged part, the charges will have settled in a state where the net electric field inside the bulk of the conductor is zero. Removing an uncharged bit does not change that fact, and the resulting electric field must still remian zero - now irrespective of the permittivity of the material.

Actually, I doubt that there can be zero charge density areas of a charged conducting surface (at least if the surface is connected): if there were such an area, why wouldn't the charge get redistributed to this area from other areas of the surface? So the OP's question may be just moot.

Take a charged conducting sphere, cut a deep slot around it. There will be almost no charge on the part of the surface at the bottom of the slot. Therefore, if you cut the slot deeper, there's almost no charge to redistribute. You can cut it to the point where you've split the sphere without changing the field much.

An electrically neutral conducting rod placed in an external electric field along its axis will develop a dipole moment. There will be a net zero charge density in the midplane of the rod. Adding a small charge to the conductor would shift this zero-charge plane, but it would still exist.

@JohnDoty : Your comment uses a lot of "almost" and "not much", so it does not disprove my answer.

@akhmeteli That's physics for you. All math applied to physics is approximate.

@CompassBearer :  Firstly, I would not call midplane a "surface", as it is inside the rod, secondly, I would say "external electric field" is (at least) in tension with the OP's caveat "with proper boundary conditions", and my answer says "at least if the surface is connected", whereas there can be no external electric field without remote (and unconnected) charges.

@JohnDoty : The OP considers electrostatics at the level of a certain mathematical model - the Poisson equation. I believe my answer is correct at this level, unless you prove otherwise.

@akhmeteli This is a physics site. My answer captures the physics.

@JohnDoty : I don't see any answer of yours, I only see your comments on my answer, and they don't disprove my answer. I am saying that there can be no zero charge density areas of a charged conducting surface (at least if the surface is connected), you are saying there can be "almost zero charge density areas". I don't know if what you say is correct or not, but it does not contradict my answer.

@akhmeteli Nothing in real physics is perfect. But if you insist on math, what is the lower bound on the charge density?

@JohnDoty : as worded, your question does not seem to make much sense: of course, the answer is "zero", as, for a fixed total charge of the conducting surface, the area can be arbitrarily large.

@akhmeteli Or you can make the slot arbitrarily narrow. It's not an academic issue: replacing a conductive surface with something skeletal with little effect on the field is an important practical technique.

@JohnDoty :  Again, my understanding is nothing in your comments proves my answer wrong. Again, I am saying that there can be no zero charge density areas of a charged conducting surface (at least if the surface is connected), you are saying there can be "almost zero charge density areas". I am not saying your statement is wrong, but I stand by my statement and believe it may be useful for the OP. Unless you prove my statement wrong, I don't quite see the point of our discussion.

@akhmeteli You insist on mathematical rigor that is misleading in a physical context. This is not a math site.
